# Gnuplot set a plot with linecolors

Tags: colors, gnuplot

i have encountered a strange problem which i cannot overcome.
I'm plotting data from 4 files into 1 and i want every plot to have a different linecolor. However command `lt #some number` just doesn't work, it gives different linetypes but never colours.
I'm using a script to make a file, to pipe it inside gnuplot to yield a .ps file.

```
set terminal postscript
set encoding iso_8859_1
set title 'energy difference for a polymer'
set xlabel 'n, polymer length'
set ylabel '{/Symbol D}E, eV'
set key bottom left
set xzeroaxis
set output 'deltaE_PQL.ps'
set boxwidth 0.9 relative
set style fill solid 1.0
plot 'deltaE_plotm2' u 1:2 with lines lt 1 title '| -2 {/Symbol \361}', \
'deltaE_plotm1' u 1:2 with lines lt 2 title '| -1 {/Symbol \361}', \
'deltaE_plot1' u 1:2 with lines lt 3 title '| 1 {/Symbol \361}', \
'deltaE_plot2' u 1:2 with lines lt 4 title '| 2 {/Symbol \361}'
```

Appreciate any ideas what is wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gnuplot console type and check `help postscript` and use:

```
set terminal postscript color
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: sometimes it's just a few letters more... please mark the answer as acceptable indicating that your question has been answered.